# Implement WS-Addressing in a C# DotNet Web Service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, wcf, web-services, header

I'm building a Web Service in C# with VS2008, and want to implement WS-Addressing, so the message headers look like eg below:

What do I need to add / do in VS2008 to make this happen?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
 xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
 xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
 xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wsssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
 xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
 xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
 <soap:Header>
  <wsa:To>http://messagehandler.org.com/sendmessage</wsa:To>
  <wsa:ReferenceParameters>
  </wsa:ReferenceParameters>
  <wsa:From>
   <wsa:EndpointReference>
    <wsa:Address>http://www.thirdparty.com/address</wsa:Address>
   </wsa:EndpointReference>
  </wsa:From>
  <wsa:Action>http://www.org.com/ServiceName</wsa:Action>
  <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:18367C02-8286-487b-9D35-D2EDC974ACF8</wsa:MessageID>
  <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:346CC216-5C14-496d-B6EA-7B644CAF6D48</wsa:RelatesTo>
  <wsse:Security>
  </wsse:Security>
 </soap:Header>
```

Comment: first of all, when you post code or XML, you need to mark those lines and press the "code" button (101 010) on the toolbar to format the code/XML nicely and make it visible to others